Can't run a simple example with await
I tried to run the following code from the command prompt:
const read = require('read').read;

const password = await read({
  prompt: "Password: ",
  silent: true,
  replace: "*" //optional, will print out an asterisk for every typed character 
});
console.log("Your password: " + password);

with the command node read.js and got:
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

What should I do to make this work?
Should I add exports or something like this?
I simply want it to read the password from the command line and print it.

the fact that you are using require rather than import shows that you are not using ES Modules, therefore the error is telling you that you need to use await inside an async function, or at the top level body of a module

Top level await is only available in Node version 14.8.0 and later. With { "type": "module" } specified in package.json or with file extension .mjs.
Otherwise, it's always possible to use await inside async functions:
async function readPassword ()
{
   const read = require('read').read;
   
   const password = await read
   ({
      prompt: 'Password: ',
      silent: true,
      replace: '*', // prints '*' instead of every typed character
   });
   
   console.log('Your password:', password);
}

// There's no need to await here because there's no return.
readPassword();

